# How do I remove my old faucet?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, installation, removal

I purchased [this faucet](http://www.homedepot.com/p/KOHLER-Cruette-Single-handle-pull-down-kitchen-faucet-in-Vibrant-Stainless-K-R780-VS/203012966) and it seems like an easy enough installation. The bottom of this new faucet looks like this: [image: new faucet thread]

Seems like all I have to do is screw something in and it will attach the faucet to my counter top.

My old faucet: [image: old faucet above counter top]

Doesn't seem like it has the same mechanics. This is what I see under my kitchen counter top: [image: old faucet bottom pic 1][image: old faucet bottom pic 2]

How do I get that off? I've tried twisting it as if the shaft is threaded but I don't think it was loosening at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The black collar seen on the bottom picture is what is keeping the faucet on. It is a plastic nut that screws on the threads you see to clamp the faucet onto the countertop.

That is what you need to unscrew with the basin wrench (or any other that can reach).

Comment: It was actually a metallic nut, but other than that it went pretty easily with one of these: http://www.harborfreight.com/12-inch-basin-wrench-91958.html

Answer (score 1):

That thing is so hard to twist off, you'll likely need a [basin wrench](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basin_wrench), which is also sometimes known as a sink wrench. When I took my faucet off recently, I followed [this article](http://www.wikihow.com/Replace-a-Kitchen-or-Bathroom-Faucet) for the most part. The hardest part for sure was getting that unscrewed, but luckily I found a basin wrench and it went smoother.

Comment: got myself one of these: http://www.harborfreight.com/12-inch-basin-wrench-91958.html and everything turned out fine!