# How to disconnect shower tray from drainage pipe?

Tags: plumbing, shower, pipe

I'm trying to disconnect the shower tray from the drainage pipe but the white plastic bit that looks like it could be screwed off seems stuck tight:

[image]

I'm not sure I can apply the torque needed to unscrew it both because of how stuck it seems and also because there isn't a lot of room to work with:

[image]

Out of interest here is what the drainage hole looks like on the shower tray:

[image]

And here is the whole shower tray:

[image]

Overall my goal is to lift out the shower tray and this is the only thing stopping me from doing that.  I will be putting the shower tray back in and will need to reconnect it again afterwards.

Should I cut through the brown pipe at the point where the white screw on bit currently sits and then get a new connector?  What tool should I use for this?  What part would I need to reconnect it?

Or is there a tool that someone would recommend to apply the torque needed in such a tiny space?

All advice welcome.

Comment: Maybe this would require a [basin wrench](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/52361/24242)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used a strap-wrench to undo that type of connector.

[image]

In your case there is very limited access but it would be worth an attempt.

It can be difficult if some people have previously applied a sealant - which are not normally needed as there is usually a rubber gasket.

Answer (score 1):

Google for "Bathtub drain key", it's a tool that expands to fit and grip the drain very strongly, so it can be unscrewed from the top.

Comment: I once made one by pushing [polymorph](http://www.polymorphplastic.co.uk/) slightly into the top of a shower waste's grating - it worked very well.